# select a radio button with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<input type="radio" value="True" propertyname="AmortizationTermInYears" onchange="showAmortizationTermInYears();UpdateField(this);" name="AmortizationTermInYears" id="AmortizationTermInYears" amortizationterminyearsradio="true">

<input type="radio" value="False" propertyname="AmortizationTermInYears" onchange="showAmortizationTermInYears();UpdateField(this);" name="AmortizationTermInYears" id="AmortizationTermInYears" checked="checked">
```

How can I select one of these radio buttons using Jquery when the page loads?

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?   which one do you want to select? why do they have the same id?  things should NEVER have the same id!

Comment: I think they have the same idea because of the HTML Helper extension method, but I want to check the one that has the "true" value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('input[name=AmortizationTermInYears]:nth(0)').prop("checked","checked");
```

Comment: Calling this code only works once. If you call this, then the user checks a different one, if you call this the second time, it will not work.

Comment: Using attr instead of prop might have been working by the time of posting the above answer. But this is not correct any more. Look down for the correct answer provided by Serj Sagan.

Comment: changed .attr to .prop

Answer (score 9):

This will do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("input[name='AmortizationTermInYears'][value='True']").attr("checked", "checked");
});
```

You need to search by both name and value then set the `checked` attribute.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/kAgcT/).

Comment: @slandau: for the record, if the radio button with `True` value will be the second, the answer you accepted will fail.

Answer (score 3):

Although the question is mostly about how to select an element, I do notice that everyone is using the `attr()` function and, usually, this is wrong because calling this function only works once. If you call this, then the user checks a different one, if you call this the second time, it will not work. the correct way to do it is to use `prop()`

```
$('input[name=AmortizationTermInYears]:nth(0)').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

"id" attribute should not be used again. You have given id="AmortizationTermInYears" to both radio buttons. It is wrong according to standards. Set different ids to both radio buttons.

Also you can select radio button by specifying id:

```
$('#AmortizationTermInYears').attr( "checked", "checked" );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name=AmortizationTermInYears]');
```

or

```
$('input[name=AmortizationTermInYears]:checked');
```